# WCF service getting NULL from JAVA AXIS webservice

Tags: java, c#, xml, wcf

I have a WCF service with XSD schema files sent from client. Our service create XML string from SQL SP and then deserialize it and then a request with this object is sent to our client's JAVA AXIS based web service.

Now, when ever we are requesting there service and they processed the request with out error then we are  getting response as NULL but if there is any problem at there end then we receive XML containing error details and other elements. If we use same XML in SOUPUI then we are getting proper response in every case.

We had several round of debugging with there developer, middleware and firewall guys but they show there logs and says we have sent the response and there is something fishy at your end.

We have checked every possible thing....Code,Updated schema files, recreated proxy class, setting timeout as much as 10 mins.

Could anyone help me out if i am missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days of investigation I found that the response which we are getting from client's web service is not matching with the schema which they have provided to us. After escalating, we got to know that they have rolled it out without testing. There was a spelling mistake in one of the elements and WCF doesn't give any error rather just return NULL, which is very annoying!

The reason why it was working in SOUP UI is because SOUP UI do not match response with schema.

what a mess!

Hope, this might help someone.